# Find columns with empty value in all rows of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm searching for an SQL request which gives me all columns in a table that are never populated.

For example, in a table like this one :

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5
---------+----------+----------+----------+---------
value    | NULL     | value    | value    | NULL
NULL     | NULL     | value    | value    | NULL
value    | NULL     | value    | NULL     | NULL
value    | NULL     | value    | value    | NULL
```

The request will return :

```
column 2, column 5
```

#### EDIT :

I've created this little PHP script to generate the query and print the result :

```
$columns = $sql->select("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name'");

$query = "SELECT ";
foreach($columns as $column) {
    $query .= "case when count(".$column[0].") = 0 then '".$column[0]."' end, ";
}
$query = substr($query, 0,-2);
$query .= " FROM table_name";

var_dump($sql->select($query));
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution but I don't know what you're using prior to this code to establish connection to the db. If I add before all this `$sql = new PDO('mysql:host=abcdefg;dbname=test', 'myuser', 'mypass'); ` it doesn't work. Hope you can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
select case when count(column1) = 0 then 'column 1' end,
       case when count(column2) = 0 then 'column 2' end,
       case when count(column3) = 0 then 'column 3' end,
       case when count(column4) = 0 then 'column 4' end,
       case when count(column5) = 0 then 'column 5' end
from tablename
```

I.e. count all values for a column, if 0 found return column name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works too but like @Gordon Linoff answers, do you know a more generic query because my table got 117 columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine if a column contains no values by doing:

```
select 'column2'
from table t
having max(column2) is null;
```

You can repeat this for all columns using `union all`:

```
select 'column1'
from table t
having max(column1) is null
union all
select 'column2'
from table t
having max(column2) is null
. . .
```

This returns the results on multiple rows.

If you want a single row:

```
select concat_ws(', ',
                 (case when max(column1) is null then 'column1' end),
                 (case when max(column2) is null then 'column2' end),
                 (case when max(column3) is null then 'column3' end),
                 (case when max(column4) is null then 'column4' end),
                 (case when max(column5) is null then 'column5' end)
                )
from table t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but my table have 117 columns ... That's why i'm searching for a simple query. is there a more generic way ? If not, i'll generate the query with a script